# Screen creation not working on crontab

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

I have a problem with one of my VPSs, in the main one, the command

```
 screen -dmS SCREEN_NAME node DIRECTORY
```

(Create a screen without joining it with the command "node DIRECTORY") works normally, in the second one, when I execute it in a script with `sh SCRIPT` it works, but when the script is executed through `crontab`, everything on the .sh file runs, except for this command.

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment entries that crontab is using.  It doesn't run your normal shell environment.

You will probably want to set the $PATH environment variable within crontab, or maybe even `source` your own `.profile` or `.bashrc` so that it runs as you would expect it to run inside your normal shell.

You may also want to look into using quotes with this command, because it sounds like part of it is getting ignored, which most of the time can be resolved by encasing the command or part of the command in quotes.

See [this link on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/233084/how-do-i-use-crontab-to-start-a-screen-session), which may be of some assistance.